# Keycloak admin rest api: Update password not set

Tags: java, keycloak, webclient, spring-webclient, keycloak-rest-api

I use Keycloak 11 and during the user registration process I want to trigger an email which asks the use to set a password.
I have already implemented it with restTemplate and keycloak 6 and it worked fine.
Now I use the recommended webClient.

```
@Override
    public void triggerRequiredActionUpdatePassword(String userId) {
        String url = applicationConstants.getKeykloakUsersUri()+ "/" + userId + "/execute-actions-email";
        String[] actions = new String[]{"UPDATE_PASSWORD"};
        webClient.put()
                .uri(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(actions))
                .exchange()
                .block();
    }
```

this results in no error but the required action is not set.
During the registration I also set the realm role via a seperate request and it works fine.

Does anyody know why the request throws no error but the action is not set?

I've set the admin-client as realm-admin in user required actions.

I can't use my smtp server yet, so there is none registered in keycloak but I was expecting that at least the field is set. Or is it only usable when an smtp is registered?

In addition:

I also got a pretty strange behaviour with the client. When I set the realm role with webClient.exchange, it works fine. When i use .retrieve(), the realmrole is not set.
I tried both solutions for the required action but nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the action of forcing the users to update their password without using the email capabilities, then you can change your URL from:

```
 String url = applicationConstants.getKeykloakUsersUri()+ "/" + userId + "/execute-actions-email";
```

to:

```
 String url = applicationConstants.getKeykloakUsersUri()+ "/" + userId;
```

and in the request body send a JSON like:

```
{"id":"<YOUR_USER_ID>","requiredActions":["UPDATE_PASSWORD"]}
```

For the email option you need **to configure the smtp** in your realm:

- Go to your `Realm` and click `realm settings`;
- Switch to the `Email tab`;
- Fill up the settings according to your needs. For gmail:

  - `Host` : `smtp.gmail.com`;
  - Set the Port to `587` if are using `TLS` or `465` for `SSL`;
  - Set to `ON` one of the options `Enabled TLS` or `Enabled SSL`;
  - `Enabled authentication` : `ON`.

    - set `Username` and `Password` to the the email account that you will be using to send the emails on behalf of keycloak and its password, respectively.

More detailed information can be found [here](https://codehumsafar.wordpress.com/2018/09/23/keycloak-configure-and-test-email-settings-for-realm/).

I just did a test run, and in my case, I have requested a token from the Keycloak Admin user and used the admin's access token in the body of the `PUT` request to the endpoint:

```
{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email
```

with the JSON content `'[UPDATE_PASSWORD]'`, then I configured the `smtp` of my realm following this [steps](https://codehumsafar.wordpress.com/2018/09/23/keycloak-configure-and-test-email-settings-for-realm/).

In the end, I received an email from my Keycloak configured email with the following message:

> our administrator has just requested that you update your DeepUnity account by > performing the following action(s): Update Password. Click on the link below to > start this process.

> [Link to account update](https://example.com)
>
> This link will expire within 12 hours.
>
> If you are unaware that your administrator has requested this, just
> ignore this message and nothing will be changed.